# How to Inject Vuex store into Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How would I inject vuex into Vue 3, in Vue 2 it was possible like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
})
```

But in Vue 3 how would you do it since there is no `new Vue()`.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/4.0#breaking-changes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The created store will be injected using `.use` method :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  }
})

const app = createApp({ /* your root component */ })

// Install the store instance as a plugin
app.use(store)
```

For more details check the [Vuex 4 docs](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

To use it in child component in options api, try to provide it as follows :

```
app.use(store)

app.config.globalProperties.$store=store;
```

then use it like `$store` in child components

for composition api (setup hook), you could just import the `useStore` composable function which returns the store instance :

```
import {useStore} from 'vuex'
setup(){
const store=useStore()// store instead of `$store`


}
```

Comment: Yes but will it be usable as this.$store?

Comment: I use the options api so how would I go about it.

Comment: yes, you're still able to work with options api as you did in vue 2, just add `app.config.globalProperties.$store=store;` in main.js

Answer (score 1):

Together with Router:

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './routes';
import {store} from "./store/store";

Vue.createApp(App).use(router, store).mount('#app');
```